# SSO KERBEROS ON WIN2012 R2 issues ? GSSException: Defective token detected (Mechanism level: GSSHeader did not find the right tag)

Tags: ldap, single-sign-on, kerberos

I am trying to set up a SSO in a particular configuration.
i have 2 forest in External Trust(each forest have one Domain)
one of the domain stand in the DMZ and the second on the Internal Nw.

My web Application / application server stand in DMZ and the user to grant access stand in the internal DC on the second Domain.

I created the service Principal that the webapplication host should call. i also generated the right Keytab.

i then apply the various configuration on the spring security files to integrate the new authentication Provider.

but when i try to log in in my webapplication. i have a "Windows Security Like" auth pop up. when i insert Valid AD user/pass instead of authenticating me in my web app i got forwarded to my web app auth page.
analysing the logs files. i can see entry like

**GSSException: Defective token detected (Mechanism level: GSSHeader did not find the right tag)**

**org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: Kerberos validation not succesfull**

Any suggestion ?

Comment: See https://sourceforge.net/p/spnego/discussion/1003769/thread/700b6941/#cb84

Answer (score 0):

Without providing any log files, it seems to be pretty obvious that you setup is broken. Your SSPI-based client cannot obtain an Kerberos service ticket and falls back to NTLM (because the server told him to do SPNEGO). Java does not handle NTLM. The SPNEGO token is malformed because it is not one, it is a plain NTLM type 1 message.

Comment: Hi Micheal , would you tell me if i can install some client application to initially test if my Kerberos configuration is Correct ? Not being that much expert in Kerberos is not helping me that much.